# Prob. 5, Sec. 6.2, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS, 4th ed: How to show this function is strictly decreasing using derivative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-verification, derivatives, inequality

Here is Prob. 5, Sec. 6.2, in the book *Introduction To Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Let $a > b > 0$ and let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy $n \geq 2$. Prove that $a^{1/n} - b^{1/n} < (a-b)^{1/n}$. [*Hint:* Show that $f(x) \colon= x^{1/n} - (x-1)^{1/n}$ is decreasing for $x \geq 1$, and evaluate $f$ at $1$ and $a/b$.]

My Attempt:

> We find that for $x > 1$,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  f^\prime(x) &= \frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n} - 1} - \frac{1}{n}(x-1)^{\frac{1}{n} - 1} \\
> &= \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{x^{1/n}}{x} - \frac{(x-1)^{1/n}}{x-1} \right) \\
> &= \frac{1}{nx(x-1)} \left( x^{1/n}(x-1) - x(x-1)^{1/n} \right) \\
> &= \frac{x^{1/n}(x-1)^{1/n}}{nx(x-1)} \left( (x-1) - x \right) \\
> &= -\frac{1}{nx^{1-\frac{1}{n}} (x-1)^{1-\frac{1}{n}} }. 
> \end{align}
> $$

PS (based on the answer by @auscrypt):

> We find that for $x > 1$,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  f^\prime(x) &= \frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n} - 1} - \frac{1}{n}(x-1)^{\frac{1}{n} - 1} \\
> &= \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{x^{1/n}}{x} - \frac{(x-1)^{1/n}}{x-1} \right) \\
> &= \frac{1}{nx(x-1)} \left( x^{1/n}(x-1) - x(x-1)^{1/n} \right) \\
> &= \frac{x^{1/n}(x-1)^{1/n}}{nx(x-1)} \left( (x-1)^{1-1/n} - x^{1-1/n} \right) \\
> &< 0. 
> \end{align}
> $$
>   because $1-1/n$ is positive for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq 2$ and because $0 < x-1< x$, which implies that
>   $$ 0 < (x-1)^{1-1/n} < x^{1-1/n},$$
>   and hence
>   $$ (x-1)^{1-1/n} - x^{1-1/n} < 0.$$
>
> Thus $f^\prime(x) < 0$ for all $x > 1$. Therefore the function $f$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $[1, +\infty)$. That is, for any $x > 1$ we have $f(x) < f(1)$.
>
> Now if $a > b > 0$, then $a/b > 1$, and so we have 
>   $$ f(a/b) < f(1),$$
>   that is,
>   $$ \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} - \left(\frac{a}{b} - 1\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} < 1,$$
>   which amounts to
>   $$ \frac{a^{1/n} - (a-b)^{1/n} }{ b^{1/n} } < 1, $$
>   which implies
>   $$ a^{1/n} - (a-b)^{1/n} < b^{1/n},$$
>   and hence 
>   $$ a^{1/n} - b^{1/n} < (a-b)^{1/n}, $$
>   as required.

Are there any issues with this proof?

Answer (score 7):

There is an error; the factorisation $x^{1/n}(x-1) - x(x-1)^{1/n} = x^{1/n} (x-1)^{1/n} ((x-1)-x)$ is incorrect and should be $x^{1/n}(x-1) - x(x-1)^{1/n} = x^{1/n} (x-1)^{1/n} ((x-1)^\frac{n-1}{n}-x^\frac{n-1}{n})$.

To correctly prove this, note that since $\frac{1}{n}-1$ is negative we have $x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$ is decreasing. This implies $(x-1)^{\frac{1}{n}-1} > x^{\frac{1}{n}-1} $ since $x-1<x$, and so $f'(x)$ is clearly negative as required.

Comment: thank you for the correction. Can you please also suggest as to how to proceed from that point on?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood I've edited my answer to include the corrected proof.